# How to get ISP information from MaxMind in logstash

Tags: logstash, geoip, maxmind

I am struggling with getting ISP info using Logstash GeoIP plugin with Logstash Version: 2.4.
I also tried logstash 5.0 Beta but no luck in that too.
can someone please help me in this

Comment: Your question is not clear, could you explain what you want to do, what have you done so far and what does not work? (cf http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry @baudsp Actually I was bit confused between GeoLite Legacy ASN and GeoIP2 ISP database
I was trying to use GeoIP2 ISP database which comes in new format(.mmdb) which logstash 2.4 is not supporting. Then I tried same database with logstash 5.0.0 Beta but that is also not yet supporting GeoIP2 ISP database. Now I used GeoLite ASN database and I am getting ASN name in logstash 2.4

Comment: So, you don't need help anymore?

Comment: My purpose is solved as of now. I am still not able to use GeoIP2 ISP database file with logstash. I think its an compatibility issue between logstash 2.4 and MaxMind GeoIP2 database. @baudsp Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Great! Good luck for the rest of your project